# how to sustain several projects checkins in TFS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, tfs

One TFS
Several Projects
Many .cs files...
Many Software Engineers
Many Checkins for all projects which are being developed at the same time.

Some projects ends earlier, and must be deployed, but some of the projects are not completed yet.

What we do, we comment the code parts which are belong to the incompleted projects
Are there any method better to manual methods on TFS 2008

Comment: "we comment the code parts which are belong to the incompleted projects" - you do what!!  Use Source control branching!!!!

Comment: Warning: code horror! Shudder!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look at your branching strategy before you end up with a trainwreck... See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598921.aspx) for a good guide. Each disparate release should have a branch. There is a small amount of extra effort merging code between branches but it will result in you having a repeatably testable "main" branch for each release. Also look at how you're cutting labels and how your continuous integration is set up (of instigate it if you don't have any currently).

Answer (score 1):

There's no secret out there, you have two main choices:

1) You have one branch per project that can be atomically released, then when you do a global release you merge only the branches of the projects that are ready to released to the global release branch. (it's a merge from latest)

2) All your projects are in only one branch (can be the case if you really do have a lot of project, too many to go 1 branch per project), then you must rely on traceability (whether using Work Item or a custom list of Changesets) to merge only the changesets of the ready to released projects to the global released branch. (it's a cherry pick merge of changesets)

Okay there's a third secret choice:

3) Use a blend of 1 & 2, if you have for instance 200 projects, you can certainly create something like 10 "groups of projects" to store all the projects that are related (technically or functionally) into one branch. Then you end up with 10 branch of 20 projects each with the constraint that all projects inside a branch must be "ready for release" to be merged in the global release branch.

1) is easy to implement, but won't be a good idea if you have a lots of projects (>20)
2) offers the best flexibility but you have to be pretty prepared and organized to set it up.
3) is still a mix of 1 & 2 both for pros & cons.